# How to display text over image in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt, I am having a label with its background image. The background image displays fine but not able to display over the image. How to do it? Guide me. Refer below my code how I implemented:

```
QImage image("sample.bmp");
myLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
myLabel->setGeometry(10,10,78,78);
```

I tried the `QPalette` to display text , but if i use `QPalette` only text is showing, image is not showing. I tried the `QPalette` this way:

```
QPalette sample_palette;
sample_palette.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::white);
sample_palette.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, Qt::blue);

myLabel->setAutoFillBackground(true);
myLabel->setPalette(sample_palette);
myLabel->setText("What ever text");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a stylesheet to show the background image? This way your text will be on top of the image.

```
ui->label->setStyleSheet(QString("QLabel {background-image: url(\"img.jpg\");}"));
```

Comment: both codes are working but Hey Yo suggestion is so simple

Answer (score 3):

You can put a text on your `QImage` (not on a `QLabel`), and after it to call `setPixmap()` of your label. Try something like this:

```
QImage image("sample.bmp");
QPainter p(&image);
p.setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
p.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont::Bold));
p.drawText(image.rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Text");
myLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
```